# Implementing CollectionType in Swift with forEach giving non Optional closure variable

Tags: swift, collections, foreach

```
class SelectableArray: CollectionType, MutableCollectionType {
    private var elements = Array<Element>()

    convenience init(elements: [Element]) {
        self.init()
        self.elements = elements
    }

    var startIndex: Int { return elements.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Int { return elements.endIndex }
    subscript (index: Int) -> Element? {
        get {
            return elements[index]
        }

        set {
            elements[index] = newValue!
        }
    }
}
```

The above class forEach give the following:

```
let a = SelectableArray<String>(elements: ["a","b"])
a.forEach { (String?) -> () in
    <#code#>
}
```

I would like to know why the `Array` forEach is (String) -> Void but mine is (String?) -> Void. How can I make it to (String) -> Void?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, `subscript (index: Int) -> Element?` should be `subscript (index: Int) -> Element`.